# CodeIgniter & CSRF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

When a user is logged in, he can perform a search with a small form. This is an AJAX request to a controller. I can perform this action multiple times. However,  when I try to reload the page, the user is logged out and needs to be logged in again.

This is my JS:

```
var CFG = {
        url: '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>',
        token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
};


$(function() 
{

    $('#personen_search_result').hide();
    $('#search_alert').hide();

    $.ajaxSetup(
    {
        data: 
        {
            token:CFG.token
        }
    });

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e,x)
    {
        var result = $.parseJSON(x.responseText);
        $('input:hidden[name="token"]').val(result.token);
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            data: 
            {
                token: result.token
            }
        });
    });


    $( "#submit_personen" ).click(function(event) 
    {


        event.preventDefault();

        var namelast        = $('#namelast').val();
        var dateofbirth     = $('#dateofbirth').val();
        var rijksregisternr = $('#rijksregisternr').val();
        var email           = $('#email').val();
        var hosid           = <?php echo $this->session->hosid; ?>;


        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            data:
            {
                nameLast: namelast,
                dateofBirth: dateofbirth,
                rijksregisterNr: rijksregisternr,
                email: email, 
                hosid: hosid
            }
        });

        $('#table_personen').html("");
        $('#search_alert').html("").hide();

        $.post(CFG.url + 'persoon/js_retrieve', function(data)
        {

            if(data['status']   == 200)
            {
                var personenrows        = data['html'];
                $('#table_personen').append (personenrows);

                if (!$('#personen_search_result').is(':visible'))
                    $('#personen_search_result').slideToggle();
            }
            else if (data['status'] == 400)
            {
                var message         = data['html'];
                $('#search_alert').append(message);

                if (!$('#search_alert').is(':visible'))
                    $('#search_alert').slideToggle();
            }
        }, 'json');


    });
});
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function js_retrieve()
{

    // Data preperations

    // Query Builder



    if ($result->num_rows() == 0)
    {

        // No result: error message
        $data['html']       = '<span class="alert">Geen personen gevonden.</span>';
        $data['status']     = 400;
    }
    else
    {

        // Good result, show list in table
        // table header 
        $html               = '<thead class="thead-light"><tr><th>Naam</th>th>Voornaam</th><th>Geboortedatum</th><th>Rijksregister</th><th>status</th></tr><tbody>';

        // create rows
        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $html           .= 
                '<tr>/\n<td><a href="'. base_url( 'persoon/detail/' .$row['id']  ) .'">' . $row['NameLast'] .', '. $row['NameFirst'] . '</a></td>/\n<td>' . $row['DateofBirth'] . '</td>/\n<td>' . $row['RijksRegisterNumber'] . '</td>/\n<td>' . $row['Status'] . '</td></tr>';
        }

        // close body
        $data['html']       = $html . '</tbody>';

        // status
        $data['status']     = 200;
    }



    // Set CSRF token hash & headers        
    $data['oldtoken']       = $this->input->post('token');
    $data['token']          = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();

    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: ' . date('r'));
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    }

    // return result
    exit( json_encode($data , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) );
}
```

Anyone that can give me some guidance?

PS: These are my configs:

```
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Comment: Could you try to add the withCredentials: true at your jQuery request? It should be handled with that flag

Comment: if you reload the page without executing any AJAX call, does it ask for the login credentials as well? knowing this would isolate the problem and exclude the entire AJAX matter.

Comment: thats strane the `$config['csrf_regenerate']=FALSE; ` option disables token regeneration on every submit. But, do so with caution. This can open you up to certain types of attacks.\

Comment: I've added the withCredentials: $.ajaxSetup(
  {
   data: 
   {
    token:CFG.token
   },
   xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
   },
   crossDomain: true
  });
But the issue remains. Without ajax requests I can reload the page safely without relogin needed

Comment: Try removing the `header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');` from your `js_retrieve()` method.

Comment: @Brad : same result ... I was thinking of that too. This just frustrates me so much at the moment. I seem to miss something and cannot figure out what.

Comment: Well, something in that `js_retrieve()` method is killing your logged in session. You may need to comment everything out and reactivate line-by-line until you find the culprit. If using `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to pass `credentials: 'same-origin'` didn't fix it, then it's probably not an issue with the AJAX request.

Comment: I notice that my session variables cannot be retrieved in the js_retrieve() method. So it must be something related to my session...?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much of an answer as it is a troubleshooting test too long for a comment. Try this:

```
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
$this->output->_display();
exit;
```